# Parsing ‘The time’ from Dicken’s Novel “Little Dorrit”

Tags: syntactic-analysis, charles-dickens

> **The time** he had reserved in his mind arriving, he sent Mr Tinkler, his valet, to Mrs General’s apartment (which would have absorbed about a third of the area of the Marshalsea), to present his compliments to that lady, and represent him as desiring the favour of an interview.

Q: How to parse the word "*The time*" in the preceding passage from Charles Dickens's *Little Dorrit Book 2*, Chapter 5

Comment: It would help us to parse your questions if you took better advantage of the formatting capabilities the site offers.  At first glance I presumed that the passage you wanted us to read was the one in bold text ... imagine my confusion.  Reviewing your struggles to understand *Little Dorrit* I see that so far your questions have generally been knocked into shape by others.

Comment: @anjan Please click [Edit] and see how the formatting is achieved, so that you can use it for future questions.

Comment: It's a participial form of a temporal clause: _When the time which he had reserved in his mind had arrived,_.  Can you parse that? Slightly different internally, same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

"[When] the time [arrived], he sent Mr Tinkler..." *The time* is identified as the one he had 'reserved in his mind': the moment when he planned to speak to Mrs General.

Answer (score 1):

***The time he had reserved in his mind arriving*** is an [absolute phrase](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/phrases.htm#absolute), which is a sentence-modifying scene-setter comprising a noun and a participle phrase.

Once you understand how these phrases work, you can understand that this one indicates that the time at which he was thinking of deploying his valet (let’s say 2 o’clock) was approaching.

You can think of structures like this as the combining of two sentences:

> ***The time [that] he had reserved in his mind was arriving. He sent Mr Tinkler, his valet, to Mrs General’s
> apartment . . .*** →
>
> ***The time** <strike>[that]</strike> **he had reserved in his mind** <strike>was</strike> **arriving**. **,**
> <strike>He</strike> **he sent Mr Tinkler, his valet, to Mrs General’s
> apartment . . .***

Answer (score 0):

"The time he had reserved in his mind arriving,": is a participle phrase.  Participal phrases like this can be used temporally or causally.

In this participle phrase, the participle has as its *'subject'* the *noun phrase* "the time he had reserved in his mind", although, strictly speaking, the participle is an adjective agreeing with the 'subject phrase'.

The usage is the descendent of a similar Latin usage, and we know that Dickens was himself a victim of what in one story he characterises as a "wicked Latin master").This type of phrase can relate the participle phrase to the rest of the sentence either temporally or causally.  That is it could (depending on the context) mean that he "sent off Mr Tinkler..." **after** the arrival of the time in question (a **temporal** connection), or **because of** the arrival of the time in question.  Or it could be **both at once**.  The advantage to using the participle phrase is that Dickens can have it both ways.  He does not have to decide between "**When** the time he had reserved in his mind  arrived" and "**since** the time her had reserved in his mind arrived."

For your information, the Latin construction in question, dreaded by school boys and girls, is known as the *ablative absolute*.  What has *absolute* got to do with it? It is a way of getting round the fact that the normal rules of grammar that otherwise forbid a participle phrase 'stranded' in this way.

But it worked all right then - people could and still can understand it; and it works all right now for the same reason.

Comment: This construction as a whole is a nominative absolute, not a participial phrase; nominative absolutes do not necessarily contain participles.

Comment: @ alphabet The construction I referred to was the Latin one.  The term 'nominative absolute' is at most metaphorical, since English nouns do not have cases in the classical sense.  Some grammarians use the term Nominative Absolute [https://englishstandarts.blogspot.com/2013/10/nominative-absolute-construction.html#:~:text=The%20Nominative%20Absolute%20Construction%20is,man%20turned%20up%20his%20collar.]  Others, such as Greenbaum in the Oxford English Grammar, do not.  That said, the metaphor makes sense to anyone aware of its Latin parent.

Answer (score -1):

The time he had reserved in his mind arriving. Is a subordinate clause of reason with a conjunction implied.

=

*As/because* the time that he had reserved in his mind had arrived.

The relative clause can be omitted:

the time arriving = (As) the time had arrived.

The time arriving is an adverbial.

{…….The…………….. time ……[*that* he had reserved in his mind]} had arrived / participle,

{Determiner …..head noun.. [………relative clause………………..]} ……...verb ………….

{………………………………….…………NP as subject….…………………..}